# How to validate for Invalid JSON vs Invalid Schema of the JSON in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema

I've been learning to handle JSON in Node.js, so it's pretty straightforward the question.

I've been asked to validate for valid schema of a JSON and valid JSON.

How is the scope for this? Which one should be validated first and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First validate if the JSON is valid, then it's schema.

You cannot validate JSON schema if the string is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

That being said, of course you can JSON.stringify a string version of JSON